# Attempting to display specific custom attributes in a particular table format

Tags: magento2, attributes, template

This may not be the best place to ask this question as it might be more of a php question but I took up building a Magento site as a hobby during covid-lockdown so I thought I'll ask here - apologies in advance.

I have a need to display certain custom attributes of a product in a particular format. I achieved it by creating a custom tab and calling the value of each attribute. Here is how the table appears and this is the desired format:

[image: Desired Table Output]

Here is a sample of the code for the table:

```
           <tr>
      <th class="col label" scope="row"><u>Average Quantity</u></th>
      <td class="col data" data-th="Average Quantity"><u>per Serving</u></td>
        <td class="col data" data-th="Average Quantity"><u>per 100g</u></td>        
       <?php if($product->getData('energy_serve')): ?>
    <tr>
      <th class ="col label" scope="row">Energy</th>
      <td class="col data" data-th="Energy"><?php echo $product->getData('energy_serve') ?></td>
      <td class="col data" data-th="Energy"><?php echo $product->getData('energy_100g') ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
      <?php if($product->getData('protein_serve')): ?>
    <tr>
      <th class="col label" scope="row">Protein</th>
      <td class="col data" data-th="Protein"><?php echo $product->getData('protein_serve') ?></td>
        <td class="col data" data-th="Protein"><?php echo $product->getData('protein_100g') ?></td>
      </tr>
      <?php endif; ?>
```

Not that great. The label is hardcoded. And there will be more attributes, I haven't created them all yet. So, I tried to get these specific attributes to display as they do with the default template for visible attributes using **Magento_Catalog::product/view/attributes.phtml** template

I couldn't manage to get them display correctly this way. I could only manage it by turning the table the other way. So the table looks like this:

[image: Undesirable table format]

And here is the code for this table:

```
* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Attributes

$_helper = $this->helper(Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output::class);
$_product = $block->getProduct();
$includeAttr = ['energy_serve',
            'protein_serve',
            'fat_total_serve',
            'fat_saturated_serve',
            'carbohydrate_serve',
            'sugar_serve',
            'sodium_serve',];   
 $includeAttrExtra = [ 'energy_100g',
            'protein_100g',
            'fat_total_100g',
            'fat_saturated_100g',
            'carbohydrate_100g',
            'sugar_100g',
            'sodium_100g'];                                 
$_additionalData = [];
$_additionalDataExtra = [];
$attributes = $_product->getAttributes();
   foreach ($attributes as $attribute) {
   
    if ($attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !$attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $includeAttr)) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
            $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
        }
        if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
            $_additionalData[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                'value' => $value,
                'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
            ];
            
        }
    }
   
    if ($attribute->getIsUserDefined() && !$attribute->getIsVisibleOnFront() && in_array($attribute->getAttributeCode(), $includeAttrExtra)) {
        $value = $attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
        if ($attribute->getFrontendInput() == 'price' && is_string($value)) {
            $value = $this->priceCurrency->convertAndFormat($value);
        }
        if (is_string($value) && strlen($value)) {
            $_additionalDataExtra[$attribute->getAttributeCode()] = [
                'label' => __($attribute->getStoreLabel()),
                'value' => $value,
                'code' => $attribute->getAttributeCode(),
            ];
        }
    }
}
?>

<tr>
      <th class="col label" scope="col"><u>Average Quantity</u></th>
      <?php foreach ($_additionalData as $_data): ?>
      <th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_data['label']) ?></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <th class="col label" scope="col"><u>per Serving</u></th>
      <?php foreach ($_additionalData as $_data): ?>
      <td class="col data" data-th="per Serving"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
      <?php endforeach; ?>
      </tr>
      <tr> 
      <th class="col label" scope="col"><u>per 100g</u></th>
      <?php foreach ($_additionalDataExtra as $_data): ?>
      <td class="col data" data-th="per 100g"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </tr>
```

As you can see I had to split the attributes to achieve this. I'm not sure if I need to - to get the labels and values in separate array? I tried following some other advice about counting and outputting a different result on each second attribute but I kept breaking the page no matter what I tried. I'm sure I'm not implementing this properly:

```
    <tr>
<?php
foreach($i=1; $count($additionalData as $i => $_data); $i++;):
if($i % 2 == 1);
    echo "<th class="col label" scope="row"><?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_data['label']) ?></th>";
    echo "<td class="col data" data-th="per serving"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>";   
   if($i % 2 == 0) 
echo "<td class="col data" data-th="per 100g"><?= /* @noEscape */ $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>";
echo "</tr><tr>";?></tr>
```

So my question really is, what do I need to do to the custom attribute array to output the data into the desired table format? What I'm trying to do is only display the label once and I'm not sure if that approach is best. Maybe my first attempt is best since it technically works as desired? I would appreciate some guidance, please.